# siunitx: What changes are needed to make an old code work with version 3?

Tags: tables, siunitx, xltabular

I would like to know the minimum changes needed to make this old code of `siunitx` work with the new version 3.

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}

\usepackage{siunitx,xltabular,multicol,booktabs,ragged2e}
\usepackage[table]{xcolor}

\newcolumntype{Y}[1]{>{\Centering\hsize=#1\hsize\linewidth=\hsize}X} % e.g. Y{1.5}
\newcolumntype{L}{>{\RaggedRight}X}

\newcommand{\heading}[1]{\multicolumn{2}{c}{#1}}

\begin{document}
    
    \rowcolors{2}{gray!15}{}
    \setlength{\tabcolsep}{0mm}
    
    \begin{xltabular}[c]{0.75\linewidth}{%
            >{\hsize=1.6\hsize\linewidth=\hsize}L<{\hspace{1ex}}
            Y{0.4}<{\hspace{1ex}}
            S[
            table-format = 4.3,
            scientific-notation = false,
            table-parse-only, 
            table-number-alignment = right,
            round-mode = off,
            tight-spacing = true,
            ]<{\hspace{2ex}}
            s[
            table-unit-alignment = left,
            per-mode = symbol,
            bracket-unit-denominator,
            sticky-per
            ]
        }
        \toprule[1.5pt]
        Parameter & Symbol & \heading{Value} \\
        \midrule
        \endfirsthead
        \midrule \noalign{\global\rownum=1}\showrowcolors
        Parameter & Symbol & \heading{Value} \\
        \midrule
        \endhead
        %
        \midrule
        \endfoot
        %
        \bottomrule[1.5pt]
        \endlastfoot
        %
        Area & A & 1.6 & \m\squared \\ 
        Volume & V & 5.7e-04 & \m\cubed \\ 
        Area & A & 1.6 & \m\squared \\ 
        Volume & V & 5.7e-04 & \m\cubed \\ 
    \end{xltabular}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Try `\usepackage{siunitx}[v2]` in your preamble...

Comment: @PaulGaborit Thanks for the hint but I actually need to work with version 3 from now on.

Comment: The author gave me this link that helps a lot: https://github.com/josephwright/siunitx/blob/main/CHANGELOG.md (the entry for 3.0.0.is quite the one...)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are two issues here. The first is that I've removed the `s`-type column. It was *very* specialised and used up one of the limited number of column letters. Moreover, the basic idea is easily covered using the `collcell` package. Adding on the optional argument makes life a bit more tricky, but it can still be sorted with

```latex
\usepackage{collcell}
\newcolumntype{s}{>{\collectcell\si}c<{\endcollectcell}}
\makeatletter
\expandafter\renewcommand\expandafter*\expandafter
  {\csname NC@rewrite@s\endcsname}[1][]%
  {%
    \@temptokena\expandafter
      {%
        \the\@temptokena
        >{\collectcell\si}c<{\endcollectcell}%
       }%
    \NC@find
  }
\makeatother
```

which will work in v2 or v3. If you know you are using v3, you can replace `\si` by `\unit`.

The second is trivial: it looks like I forgot to cover `round-mode = off`. That can be fixed at the moment using

```latex
\ExplSyntaxOn
\keys_define:nn { siunitx }
  { round-mode / off .code:n = \keys_set:nn { siunitx } { round-mode = none } }
\ExplSyntaxOff
```

and will be sorted properly in the next maintenance release.

Comment: Your edits did the trick for `s` column, however, I can't left-align the units when writing `s[table-text-alignment = left]`. Also, `\newcolumntype{s}{>{\RaggedRight\collectcell\si}c<{\endcollectcell}}` doesn't help me left-align the units.

Comment: @Diaa Try `\newcolumntype{s}{>{\collectcell\si}l<{\endcollectcell}}`

Comment: Kindly, check the issues I found in my follow-up question https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/600980/2288.

Comment: I don't think that the code for the optional argument is correct. It grabs the argument and so avoids an error, but it doesn't process it, an so everything is ignored.