# siunitx v3: How to create a table unit column to be as customizable as that of version 2?

Tags: tables, siunitx

Following up [this answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/600854/2288), I need the table unit column `s`, in the following, to

1- respect the options `[per-mode = symbol, bracket-unit-denominator, sticky-per, inter-unit-product = \ensuremath{{\cdot}}]` I pass to it and

2- have two more options for adjusting its width and units left-center-right alignment.

[image]

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}

\usepackage{siunitx,xltabular,multicol,booktabs,ragged2e}
\usepackage[table]{xcolor}

\usepackage{collcell}
\newcolumntype{s}{>{\collectcell\si}l<{\endcollectcell}}
\makeatletter
\expandafter\renewcommand\expandafter*\expandafter
{\csname NC@rewrite@s\endcsname}[1][]%
{%
    \@temptokena\expandafter
    {%
        \the\@temptokena
        >{\collectcell\si}l<{\endcollectcell}%
    }%
    \NC@find
}
\makeatother

\parindent=0pt

\begin{document}
    \rowcolors{2}{gray!15}{}
    \setlength{\tabcolsep}{0mm}
    \begin{xltabular}{0.5\linewidth}{%
            X X
            S[
            table-format = 4.3e-1,
            parse-numbers = true,
            table-alignment-mode = none,
            table-number-alignment = right,
            exponent-mode = input,
            exponent-product = \times,
            round-mode = none,
            tight-spacing = true,
            ]<{\hspace{2ex}}
            s[
            per-mode = symbol, 
            bracket-unit-denominator, 
            sticky-per,
            inter-unit-product = \ensuremath{{\cdot}},
            ]
        }
        Area & A & 14.643  & \m\squared \\ % 
        Volume & V & 5.7e-04  & \m\cubed \\ % 
        Area & A & 1212.6 & \m\squared \\ % 
        Specific Heat  & c & 5.7e-04 &  \J\per\kg\K \\ % 
    \end{xltabular}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Have you tried `\unit` instead of `\si`? In any case it should be explained in the v3 manual

Comment: @daleif Yes, I have. It didn't matter.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The following defines a column `s` that takes an optional argument (that's `siunitx` options which should be applied inside that column), followed by a mandatory argument (that's the column type on which this should be imposed, any of the standard columns should work here so `l`, `c`, `r`, `p`, etc.).

```
\documentclass[]{article}

\usepackage{siunitx}
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{collcell}

\makeatletter
\@ifpackageloaded{mdwtab}
  {\newcolumntype{s}[2][]{>{\sisetup{#1}\collectcell\unit}#2<{\endcollectcell}}}
  {%
    \newcolumntype{s}{}%
    \renewcommand*\NC@rewrite@s[2][]
      {%
        \@temptokena\expandafter
          {%
            \the\@temptokena
            >{\sisetup{#1}\collectcell\unit}#2<{\endcollectcell}%
          }%
        \NC@find
      }%
  }
\makeatother

\begin{document}
% centred
\begin{tabular}
  {
    |
    S[table-format = 4.3e-1,
      parse-numbers = true,
      table-alignment-mode = none,
      table-number-alignment = right,
      exponent-mode = input,
      exponent-product = \times,
      round-mode = none,
      tight-spacing = true,
      ]<{\hspace{2ex}}
    |
    s[per-mode = symbol, 
      bracket-unit-denominator, 
      sticky-per,
      inter-unit-product = \ensuremath{{\cdot}}]{c}
    |
  }
  1.5 & \ohm \\
  2.5 & \ohm\second \\
  3.5 & \second\per\ohm \\
\end{tabular}

% specifying width
\begin{tabular}
  {
    |
    S[table-format = 4.3e-1,
      parse-numbers = true,
      table-alignment-mode = none,
      table-number-alignment = right,
      exponent-mode = input,
      exponent-product = \times,
      round-mode = none,
      tight-spacing = true,
      ]<{\hspace{2ex}}
    |
    s[per-mode = symbol, 
      bracket-unit-denominator, 
      sticky-per,
      inter-unit-product = \ensuremath{{\cdot}}]{p{5cm}}
    |
  }
  1.5 & \ohm \\
  2.5 & \ohm\second \\
  3.5 & \second\per\ohm \\
\end{tabular}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Usage inside `xltabular` (with generalization to also work with `mdwtab` that is not necessary for this MWE)

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}

\usepackage{siunitx}
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{collcell}
\usepackage{xltabular}
\usepackage[table]{xcolor}

\usepackage{collcell}

\makeatletter
\@ifpackageloaded{mdwtab}
  {\newcolumntype{s}[2][]{>{\sisetup{#1}\collectcell\unit}#2<{\endcollectcell}}}
  {%
    \newcolumntype{s}{}%
    \renewcommand*\NC@rewrite@s[2][]
      {%
        \@temptokena\expandafter
          {%
            \the\@temptokena
            >{\sisetup{#1}\collectcell\unit}#2<{\endcollectcell}%
          }%
        \NC@find
      }%
  }
\makeatother

\begin{document}
\rowcolors{2}{gray!15}{}
\setlength{\tabcolsep}{0mm}
\begin{xltabular}{0.5\linewidth}
  {%
    X
    X
    S[table-format = 4.3e-1,
      parse-numbers = true,
      table-alignment-mode = none,
      table-number-alignment = right,
      exponent-mode = input,
      exponent-product = \times,
      round-mode = none,
      tight-spacing = true]
      <{\hspace{2ex}}
    s[per-mode = symbol, 
      bracket-unit-denominator, 
      sticky-per,
      inter-unit-product = \ensuremath{{\cdot}}]
      {c}
  }
    Area & A & 14.643  & \m\squared \\ % 
    Volume & V & 5.7e-04  & \m\cubed \\ % 
    Area & A & 1212.6 & \m\squared \\ % 
    Specific Heat  & c & 5.7e-04 &  \J\per\kg\K \\ % 
\end{xltabular}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Would you please use my question exact code using `xltabular` and the same columns number and type in your answer since I have errors when trying to make my question code work with your solution?

Comment: @Diaa done. I guess you forgot the mandatory argument.

Comment: Many thanks. One final question if you don't mind: if I have a column defined by `\newcolumntype{Y}[1]{>{\Centering\hsize=#1\hsize\linewidth=\hsize}X}`, can I use it as a unit column in your answer?

Comment: @Diaa yes, this should work. Just use `s[<options>]{Y}` and you should be good to go.

Comment: Thanks for the help to make it work.

Comment: @Diaa I totally forgot the mandatory argument of `Y` :) So it should be `s[<options>]{Y{<some length>}}` instead (the mandatory argument of `s` must include everything that's necessary for the other column).

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/126382/discussion-between-diaa-and-skillmon).